# cd command fails when directory is extracted from windows file

Tags: windows, bash, shell, cd

I have one text file in windows that contains lots of directories that I need to extract.
I tried to extract one directory and tried to `cd` to it in a shell script, but the `cd` command failed, with prompting `cd: /VAR/GPIO/: No such file or directory`.

I have confirmed that the directory exists in my local PC and the directory is correct (though it is relative). I have also searched a lot, seems some special windows characters exist in the extract file. I tried to see them with `cat -A check` and the result is **`^[[m^[[K^[[m^[[KVAR/GPIO/$`**

I don't even know what the meaning of the `m^` or `[[K`.
Could you please help me about this problem? I use Cygwin in Windows 7 64-bit.
Below is my related code for review:

```
templt_dir=$(cat temp | grep -m 1 "$templt_name" |head -1 | sed -n "s#$templt_name##p" | sed -n "s#\".*##p")
echo $templt_dir     ###comment, it runs output: /VAR/GPIO/, that's correct!
cd $templt_dir       ###comment, cd error prompts
cat temp | grep -m 1 "$templt_name" |head -1 | sed -n "s#$templt_name##p" | sed -n "s#\".*##p" > check  ###comment, for problem checking
```

Below is the content of the `check` file:

```
$ cat -A check
^[[m^[[K^[[m^[[KVAR/GPIO/$
```

To confirm my directory is correct, below is the results of `ls -l` on `/VAR`:

```
$ ls VAR -l
total 80K
drwxrwx---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users 0 Jun 24 11:11 Analog/
drwxrwx---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users 0 Jun 24 11:37 Communication/
drwxrwx---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users 0 Jun 24 11:10 GPIO/
drwxrwx---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users 0 Jun 24 11:11 HumanInterface/
drwxrwx---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users 0 Jun 24 11:11 Memory/
drwxrwx---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users 0 Jun 24 11:11 PWM/
drwxrwx---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users 0 Jun 24 11:10 Security/
drwxrwx---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users 0 Jun 24 11:11 System/
drwxrwx---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users 0 Jun 25 16:25 Timers/
drwxrwx---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users 0 Jun 24 11:10 UniversalDevice/
```

Comment: Did you write a program to do this?  If so, please show the code.

Comment: Hi wallyk,  I'm a new stackoverflow user, I cannot attach picture. I will paste my code in updated post, please help to review, thanks!

Comment: You don't need to upload a picture.  Edit your question, and copy and paste the code into the question.  Then select the code and type Ctrl-K for format it as code.

Comment: You need to convert the Windows file to Linux format. You can do this using `dos2unix` tool.

Comment: Are you sure `/VAR/GPIO` is correct? Paths are case sensitive.

Comment: yes, /VAR/GPIO/ is correct.

Comment: Hi iqstatic, in fact, I have many windows files that contains the dir information, and the number or name is variable with time, I use grep to collect all the dir information I need to further processing.

Comment: How do you created this `temp` file? It looks like an output of `ls` or something, so maybe you have to remove an alias that prints colors to get rid of these characters.

Comment: Hi @fedorqui,  the temp file is created from the combination of "grep" and "sed" commands output redirection, and I use grep with 
`find ./* -name *.tpar | grep --color=always -rin "<template template=" | sed 's#.*<template template=##g' | sed 's#"##' | sed 's#\\#\/#g' > temp`
so, you think the problem is caused by color option in grep?

Comment: @cmjauto absolutely. Try `find ./* -name *.tpar | grep --color=always -rin "<template template=" > file` and open the `file` with a normal editor. You will see it contains these strange characters. Just say `\grep` to use the normal `grep` without any alias: `find ./* -name *.tpar | \grep  -rin "<template template="` and see it doesn't have any of these characters.

Comment: Hi @fedorqui, yes, I see many prefix of "[ESC][mESC[KESC[mESC[K" in each line with notepad++, that's the key point. Thank you for your suggestions! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message `cd: /VAR/GPIO/: No such file or directory` indicates that
the name stored in `$templt_dir` doesn’t exist.

This is actually due to the string containing non-printing [ANSI escape
sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).
You need to remove these characters from the string containing the directory.

I found the following sed substitution from [this Unix and Linux answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4533/22812)

```
sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g"
```

which you should include in your pipe command:

```
templt_dir=$(grep -m 1 "$templt_name" temp | sed -n "s#$templt_name##p; s#\".*##p" | sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g")
```

*Note:* I concatenated your two `sed` substitutions into the one command and I removed the unnecessary `cat`. I also removed the redundant `head -1` since `grep -m 1` should only output one line. You can probably combine all the sed substitutions into one: `sed -r "s#$templt_name##; s#\".*##; s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g"` (the `-n` sed option and `p` sed command can be left out if there’s only line being processed but I can’t test this without having the original file).

Other ways of using `sed` to strip ANSI escape sequences are listed at [Remove color codes (special characters) with sed](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3584/remove-color-codes-special-characters-with-sed).

However, a better long-term fix would be to modify the process which creates the text file listing the directories to not include ANSI Escape codes in its output.

Comment: Hi @Anthony Geoghegan, thanks, it works!

For another, you mentioned that the root cause of this problem is that the original source windows files, yes, however, I have to deal with these files in windows environment.
Thanks again for your time and great help, sincerely!

Comment: @cmjauto Glad to help. That was a tricky problem but you've edited your question so that it's good one and deserves an upvote. Welcome to Stack Overflow! BTW, I updated my answer to include further suggestions on improving your pipe command.

Comment: Hi @Anthony Geoghegan, great thanks for your help and advice! yes, I'm new to shell script :) I will keep going with the shell, ^_^